# Docker registry frontend

Tags: docker-registry

I'm trying to setup a *trivial* private repository using the [official registry image](https://hub.docker.com/_/registry/) and [kwk/docker-registry-frontend](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend) as a frontend.

My docker run command for the registry

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:5000:5000 \
--restart=always \
--name registry \
registry:2
```

My docker run command for the frontend

```
docker run \
-d \
--name registry-frontend \
-e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=127.0.0.1 \
-e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_PORT=5000 \
-p 192.168.88.142:80:80 \
konradkleine/docker-registry-frontend:v2
```

I can push images to the repository *directly*:

```
docker tag some-local-image localhost:50000/my-name/my-local-image
docker push localhost:50000/my-name/my-local-image
```

When I navigate to the frontend in my browser (http://192.168.88.142), the frontend loads, however the image is not listed...

This seems about the most basic setup possible; what am I missing?

Comment: On a side-note, I would use docker-compose, otherwise those parameters to `run` are stored only in the current container, and when you need to upgrade or whatever, they are lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](https://github.com/kwk/docker-registry-frontend/issues/144#issuecomment-233525716) pointed me in the right direction.

I'd thought `-e ENV_DOCKER_REGISTRY_HOST=127.0.0.1` was relative to the networking stack on the docker host. Turns out it's from the perspective of the container!

Using a LAN address for the docker registry proper solved it.